# Is it safe to reinterpret_cast from std::function<void()> * to std::function<std::monostate()> *?

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast, monostate

Example:

```
std::function<std::monostate()> convert(std::function<void()> func){
    return *reinterpret_cast<std::function<std::monostate()> * >(&func);
}
```

Are `std::function<void()>` and `std::function<std::monostate()>` considered "similar" enough for `reinterpret_cast` to be safe?

Edit: someone asked me to clarify what I am asking. I am not asking if the general case of foo<X> and foo<Y> are similar but whether foo<void> and foo<std::monostate> are.

Comment: Why do you think it's safe? Spoiler: it's not, but can you explain why you believe it might be safe?

Comment: My instinct tells me no, because they are just two different types, but there might be an exception hidden somewhere in the standard that technically allows this, so maybe the language-lawyer tag will help.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I was looking at the assembly code of std::monostate() functions and void() functions and they generate the same assembly verbatim.

Comment: Per language, it is UB. Though it might work anyway on many implementations https://godbolt.org/z/11vYqsY5e, as `std::monostate` is an empty trivial type, meaning the code is often the same for returning void or monostate.

Comment: The assembly code of `std::monostate()` functions and `void()` functions has no direct relevance on specific instantiations of the `std::function` template.

Comment: @NicolBolas bitmask added language-lawyer, whether OP intended or not.

Comment: IIRC, the standard does allow a function pointer of one type to be casted to a function pointer of another type.  But casting a `std::function<X>*` pointer to a `std::function<Y>*` pointer, where `X` and `Y` are not the same type, is a completely different thing and would be UB, or at least a Strict-Aliasing violation, even if casting the underlying function pointers were "allowed".

Comment: `return [func]{ func(); return std::monostate{}; };` ... untested.

Comment: `template_name<T>` and `template_name<U>` are two different unique types.  The only thing they have in common is the name of the template that instantiates them

Comment: @Eljay I am aware of that, but that isn't tail call optimized because the compiler thinks it has to create an object.

Comment: @user2999815: You're calling through a `std::function`; that automatically throws away a bunch of optimizations.

Comment: If I remove some irrelevant details from the question, it looks like your question is: *If I have a class template named `foo` and types `X` and `Y`, are `foo<X>` and `foo<Y>` considered "similar" enough for a `reinterpret_cast` from `foo<Y>*` to `foo<X>*` to be safe?* Did I miss any details that would be relevant to [the rules for being similar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing)? (If so, could you explain why they might be relevant? Note that "assembly code" is not covered by the C++ standard.)

Comment: **Addendum:** It might be that you see a relation between the `X` and `Y` in my preceding comment. If so, you might consider that to be a relevant detail that I missed, and you should mention that. This is one sort of detail that would help people come up with an answer you might find useful. It's rather hard to guess at your thought process when your question is so devoid of details.

Comment: @JaMiT Yes. I want to know specifically if foo<void> and foo<std::monostate> are similar enough. I mean, some languages don't even distinguish between them.

Answer (score 2):

No this is unsafe and leads to undefined behavior.  In particular, there's no guarantee that the two layouts will be compatible.  Of course, you might get away with it with some compiler and runtime combinations, but then it might break if some future release of your compiler decides to implement certain forms of control flow integrity.

The safe way to do what you want, albeit at a small cost in performance, is just to return a new lambda, as in:

```
std::function<std::monostate()> convert(std::function<void()> func){
    return [func=std::move(func)]() -> std::monostate { func(); return {}; };
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Maybe a future version of gcc or clang will recognize std::monostate and void being equivalent and optimize it.

Comment: @user2999815 "generates identical assembly" is not the same as "is equivalent"

Comment: Turns out clang already optimizes `return {}`

Comment: @JaMiT You are right, these are not virtual functions.  I've corrected my answer to explain that the layouts might not be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

> Are `std::function<void()>` and `std::function<std::monostate()>` considered "similar" enough for `reinterpret_cast` to be safe?

No. Given a template `foo` and *distinct* types `X` and `Y`, the instantiations `foo<X>` and `foo<Y>` are not similar, regardless of any perceived relationship between `X` and `Y` (as long as they are not the same type, which is why they were qualified as "distinct"). Different template instantiations are unrelated unless documented otherwise. There is no such documentation for `std::function`.

The [rules for "similar"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing) make allowances for digging into pointer types, but there is nothing special for templates. (Nor could there be, since a template specialization could look radically different than its base template.) Different types as template arguments yield dissimilar templated classes. No need to dig deeper into those arguments.

---

> I am not asking if the general case of foo<X> and foo<Y> are similar but whether foo<void> and foo<std::monostate> are.

There is nothing special about `void` and `std::monostate` that would make them two names for the same type. (In fact, they cannot be the same type, as the former has zero values, while the latter has exactly one value.) So, asking about `foo<void>` and `foo<std::monostate>` is the same as asking about the general case, just with a greater possibility of seeing connections that do not exist.

Also, the question is not about `foo<void>` and `foo<std::monostate>` but about `foo<void()>` and `foo<std::monostate()>`. The types used as template arguments are function types, not object types. Function types are very particular in that two function types are the same only when all of their parameter and return types are exact matches; none of the conversions allowed when invoking a function are considered. (Not that there is a conversion from `void` to `std::monostate`.) The function types are different, so again the templates instantiated from those types are not similar.

---

Perhaps a more focused version of this question would have asked about function pointers instead of `std::function` objects.

> (*from a comment:*)  I was looking at the assembly code of std::monostate() functions and void() functions and they generate the same assembly verbatim.

Generated assembly means nothing as far as the language is concerned. At best, you have evidence that **with your compiler**, it seems likely that you could get away with invoking a function pointer after casting it from `void (*)()` to `std::monostate (*)()`. Not "safe" so much as "works for now". And that assumes that you use the function pointer directly instead of burying it inside a `std::function` (a complex adapter of types).

C++ is a strongly typed language. Different types are different even if they are treated the same at the level of assembly code. This might be more readily apparent if we switch to more familiar types. On many common systems, `char` is signed, making it equivalent to `signed char` at the assembly code level. However, this does not affect the similarity of functions. The following code is illegal, even if changing `char` to `signed char` has no effect on the assembly code generated for `foo()`.

```cpp
char foo() { return 'c'; }

int main()
{
    signed char (*fun)() = foo; // <-- Error: invalid conversion
//  ^^^^^^ -- because the return type is signed char, not char
}
```

One can downgrade this error to a warning with a `reinterpret_cast`. After all, it is legal to cast a function pointer to any function pointer type. However, it is not safe to invoke the function through the cast pointer (unless cast back to the original type), hence the warning. Invoking it might work very reliably on your system, but that is due to your system, not the language. When you ask about "safe", you are asking for guidance from the language specs, not merely what will probably work on your system.